# How to display or print WordPress memory limit and WordPress max memory limit

Tags: memory

What code do I need to use to display the WordPress memory limit and WordPress maximum memory limit.

In PHP for example, I can just get the memory limit by using:

```
echo $memory_limit = ini_get('memory_limit');
```

What would be a similar equivalent in WordPress?

Comment: That's probably still right. I don't think WordPress has a separate memory limit, does it? The limits will be from the PHP environment.

Comment: am talking of how to echo values of memory limit and maximum memory limit already set by my wordpress aplications

Comment: OK, there is [`wp_raise_memory_limit`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_raise_memory_limit/). Is that what you meant? Are your applications using this as a matter of course? They probably shouldn't be. At first glance that's just the WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT constant, if `wp_is_ini_value_changeable( 'memory_limit' )` is true.

Comment: Thanks Rup. Thats is what am looking for. You can update it as answer

Answer (score 1):

Resolved via this functions as suggested by **Rup**

```
wp_is_ini_value_changeable( 'memory_limit' )
```

source [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_raise_memory_limit/)